# Change name of a Class

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Is it possible to change the name of a class retrieved using:`Foo.class.getName()` (or `getSimpleName()` or `getCanonicalName()`).

I know that those methods are part of `java.lang.Class<T>` the question itself is if there is a way to tell `java.lang.Class<T>` what is the name that I want it to display for my class.

I know that it "opens the door to tricky things" since that name is used by the reflection libraries to do "stuff" and bla bla bla. nevertheless I was wondering wether is posible to call `Foo.class.getSimpleName()` and get something like `MyFoo`.

All of this of course without string manipulation which is the last alternative I have.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the name of a class"? A class has a name, and that's its name.

Comment: AFAIK the class name is coming straight from the `.class` file and cannot be changed at runtime.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: What's the point? Your class names are for you, the developer, not the computer and not the end user. If you need some different string associated with a class, add a method to get said string and don't over-complicate it.

Comment: Change the name retrieved when calling one of the method mentioned above (i.e: for the class `Foo` if i call `Foo.class.getName()` even when the name of the class IS IN DEED `Foo`, i want to see `my_foo_class`, I was wondering if there is a way that I can say that the name of my class is my_foo_class, I am thinking that maybe I need to create a `ClassLoder` for Foo which will change its name to be something else when the class is loaded, but before going that way or start manipulating strings I want to hear what does more experienced guys have to say

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the purpuse... lets say that I want to create a class to represent primitive values (i know I can call `int.class` but this returns the `Integer` class, and after that there is no way to know if it it was `Integer` or `int` therefor I want something like `PrimitiveInt.class.getSimpleName()` => `int` (of course instead of putting it like that in code I'll be receiving the class as a parameter, and the call for a `Class<?> param` -> `param.getSimpleName()`

Comment: I still don't see the point.  Add a `getMySpecialClassName ()` method to the base class / interface and define it to your desires I classes that implement it.

Comment: that would never work for all the classes, only for the ones that I create, I want something that I can call from several places in my code  without having the need of another class to do the job of translating the names if they belong to a class or another specially because that will mean a lot of `if's` (or your decision maker of preference) in the code making it also more expensive for my processor and extremely verbose in my code

Answer (score 1):

Find the src.zip in your JDK. Extract `java/lang/Class.java` into some directory and modify `getSimpleName()` method. For example like this:

```
public String getSimpleName() {
    return "MyName"; // return MyName for any class
}
```

Compile it normally with javac (you will get many warnings, ignore them). Remove all additional classes created like `Class$1.class`, leaving only `java/lang/Class.class` file. Put it into jar:

```
$ jar -c java >myclass.jar
```

Now prepend the bootstrap path with your new jar. For example, let's consider this test class:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Test.class.getSimpleName());
   }
}

$ java Test
Test

$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:myclass.jar Test
MyName
```

I don't even want to explain how dangerous it is. Also according to the [Oracle binary code license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) (supplemental term F) you cannot deploy your application this way.

Comment: hahahah yup that should work... too dangerous for me hahahah, I think from that option and the one of implementing my own classloader I rather the class loader, but thanks hehehe

Comment: @tagir a bit sarcastic but well explained  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which according to their home page allows mocking `final` classes although it needs to use it's own class loader.

Other mocking frameworks that do not do byte code manipulation with custom class loaders such as [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito) and Easymock cannot work with classes that are `final` which [`java.lang.Class`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java?av=f#115) is.

Comment: yup as I mention in one of the comments to my answer I probably need to create my own class loader, I was wondering if there is an easier way